# Adding items to a listbox from a different class

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I want to add items to a listbox which is called 'mainFormRego'. The method works if I call it inside the MainForm class where it is located, but if I try to call it in a different class it doesnt work. I have instantiated the callback. Please help me I am lost for ideas and have been trying for a while to find a solution. I am using C# and windows forms.

**MainForm class** (where listbox is located)

```
namespace VehicleSystem
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
public void updateDisplay()
        {
            mainFormRego.Items.Clear();
            foreach (Vehicle item in Business.VehicleList)
            {
                mainFormRego.Items.Add(item.Rego);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Add Vehicle Class**

```
namespace VehicleSystem
{
    public partial class AddVehicle : Form
    {
        public void addVehicle(string _rego, string _make, string _model, string _year, string _dailycharge)
        {
            MainForm fm = new MainForm();
            fm.updateDisplay();
            string[] inputs = { _rego, _make, _model, _year, _dailycharge };
            bool status = true;
            foreach (Vehicle item in Business.VehicleList)
            {
                if (item.Rego.ToString() == _rego)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error! Invalid input, please try agaian.", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    status = false;
                } else
                {
                    status = true;
                }
            }

            if (inputs.Any(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error! Invalid input, please try agaain.", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            } else if ( _year.Any(char.IsDigit) == false || _dailycharge.Any(char.IsDigit) == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error! Invalid input, please try agaain.", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            } else if (status == true)
            {
                Business.VehicleList.Add(new Vehicle() { Rego = _rego, Make = _make, Model = _model, Year = _year, DailyCharge = _dailycharge });
                this.Close();
            }
        }
   }
}
```

**Vehicle List**

```
namespace VehicleSystem
{
    class Business
    {
        public const String fileName = "C:\\Users\\tbyrm\\Documents\\Workspace\\SDV601\\sdv601-s1-21-project-travisbyr\\save.dat";

        private static List<Vehicle> vehicleList = new List<Vehicle>();

        public static List<Vehicle> VehicleList { get => vehicleList; set => vehicleList = value; }

        public static void Save()
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(fileStream, VehicleList);
            }
        }

        public static void Retrieve()
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                VehicleList = (List<Vehicle>)formatter.Deserialize(fileStream);
            }
        }

        public static void RemoveVehicle(string rego)
        {
            VehicleList.RemoveAll((x) => x.Rego == rego);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help! Any help is appreciated many thanks.

Comment: How do you fill Business.VehicleList? What is the technology? Is it WinForms, WPF, or something else?

Comment: what is the error?what you mean by it doesn't work. Is that access issue?

Comment: @AdamJachocki using windows forms see attached

Comment: @Ramji I get no error it just doesnt work when called

Comment: Source of all related problem: `MainForm fm = new MainForm();` in `addVehicle()`: you're creating a new Instance of the MainForm class, not related to the existing. Calling its `updateDisplay()` of course won't do anything.

Comment: @Jimi Can you please provide a code example so that I can fix it?

Answer (score -1):

The issue is due to the following line within `AddVehicle`:

```
MainForm fm = new MainForm();
```

You are creating a *new* instance of `MainForm` rather than referencing the currently active instance being displayed. Therefore, you are correctly updating a list but not the list you are expecting (list updated on new instance of MainForm not being displayed).

**Try passing a reference to `mainFormRego` and update within another `class`.**

Comment: Could you please write in code how I would do that are where? Thanks so much!